# Page not refresh in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created simple application in which I setup login and logout. I am noticing that when I `this.props.history.push("/");` it does change url but it is not changing content of page, as I have in NavBar login and logout button but that one remain same.

Here is code from where I am pushing page to home, it is logout functionality.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const Logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
  return <Redirect to='/' />
}

export default Logout;
```

So this should change my navbar instead of Logout to login, but it just change url in browser but no change in content of page. Following my home page code

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <h1>Home page</h1>
    </Container>

      );
  }

export default Home;
```

Is there any thing else I have to do to refresh content. I have nothing on my home page.

Comment: Try wrap Logout component with withRouter(Logout);

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';